# codeigniter: accessing a callback from config/form_validation.php config file

Tags: codeigniter, callback, validation, config

Callback functions are not executing from my form_validation config file when called upon.  Am I correct when assuming the reason for the non-execution is due to the location of the callback function?  For the callback to execute, it will have to be placed inside the config file or have the $config array placed into the controller file?  If that is the case, what avenue do you suggest I take or do something completely different to accomplish this?

The more I learn about CI the more I want to use its clean structure.

-Thank You,
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callback functions are placed within the same controllers or models from which they are called in form validation. Maybe in this case you need to put your callback function into a global controller liker MY_controller.php.

Comment: Where in the CI user-guide can I read about "global controllers?"  
  
-Thanks

Comment: @mikeds After reading, I still am not sure which route to take.  I am trying to keep this as clean and simple as possible.  I will also like to stay with, if possible, the $config because it is elegant looking and I can understand rules structure better. However, I stumble upon the<callback function not executing unless it is inside of the same controllers or modules from which they are called in form validation.  
  

  
-Rich

Comment: Best to put your global callbacks (e.g. login) on the global controller, and your per basis ones on the individual controller.

Comment: thank you for the direction.  I need to read up on this lingo(global controller).  What do you mean by global controller?  Are you referring to extending the validation library?

Comment: Wouldn't putting one in a helper work as well, you would only have to load it like `$this->load->helper('callback_function_helper')`